# How to convert hashSet<String> to arrayListOf?

Tags: arrays, android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences, hashset

Using shared preferences to save an arrayListOf in my app. Im converting the array to a hashset and saving it but when I load it I am unable to convert it back to an arrayListOf. I have tried toTypedArray() and toArray() but neither solve the problem. Getting the error below.

> Required:
> kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* = java.util.ArrayList */
> Found:
> (Mutable)Set<String!>?

Using the following to try and load the hashet and convert it.

```
var sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE)
var places = arrayListOf<String>()
var loadSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("key", null)

places = loadSet
go.setOnClickListener{
            thread {
                val place = newLocation.text.toString()
                var stringCounter = counter.toString()

                if(place !in places){
                    places.add(place)
                    //editor.putStringSet("key", places)
                    //editor.commit()
                    var sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE)
                    var editor = sharedPreferences.edit()



                    set.add(place)
                    editor.putStringSet("key", set);
                    editor.commit();

                    Log.d("set", set.toString())

                    var loadSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("key", HashSet<String>())?.toList()
                    Log.d("load", loadSet.toString())
                    places = loadSet as ArrayList<String>


                }
```

Answer (score 1):

`arrayListOf` isn’t a type. It’s a function. The type is ArrayList, but it’s more typical to only need the more abstract List or MutableList, depending on what you’re doing with it. For those you can use `set.toList()` or `set.toMutableList()`.

If you have an existing ArrayList or MutableList, you could also do `list.addAll(set)`.

Comment: Ok thank you that helped. But now it gives me this error instead: SingletonList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList. Any ideas on this one? Much appreciated.

Comment: I would have to see your code that generated the error.

Comment: added code the sending a loading code that i am using a certain thread. Both the Log.d for the set and load both output the correct value, so at least that is working

Comment: You didn’t use my code `.toList()` or `toMutableList()` or `list.addAll(set)`. You can’t simply cast a Set to a List. Casting doesn’t do any sort of conversion. It simply tells the compiler to treat something as a different type and to crash if it isn’t already a match for that type.

Comment: Also, you are using a thread to work with properties that you have not made threadsafe, which can cause bizarre, difficult to fix bugs. There’s no reason to use a separate thread for this code anyway because it’s non-blocking.